# How to filter a 'option set' field options, based on current status in Dynamics 365 form

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365

I have a option set field in a dynamics 365 form and I want to control the option set values available in the form dynamically so that depending on the current status, the available options should change. But it is not working using Javascript

I have the code in On Form Load event with the below code.

```
function setStatusoptions(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var statusField = formContext.getAttribute("new_status");
    
    var currentStatus = statusField.getValue();
    var allowedOptionValues = [];
    console.log("currentstat="+currentStatus);

    if (currentStatus === 717800000) {
        allowedOptionValues = [717800001,717800002];
    } else if (currentStatus === 717800001) {
        allowedOptionValues = [717800002, 717800003];
    } 
    console.log(allowedOptionValues);
    
    // Loop through all the options in the status field
    var options = statusField.getOptions();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var option = options[i];
        
       // Check if the option value is in the allowedOptionValues array
        if (allowedOptionValues.indexOf(option.value) === -1) {
            // Disable the option
            option.disabled = true;
        } else {
            // Enable the option
            option.disabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

In console, I am getting the correct current status and the filtered allowedoptions in the array. But the form field is still showing all the options instead of the allowed options as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1955), I have changed

```
var options = statusField.getOptions();
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i];

    // Check if the option value is in the allowedOptionValues array
    if (allowedOptionValues.indexOf(option.value) === -1) {
        // Disable the option
        option.disabled = true;
    } else {
        // Enable the option
        option.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

to

```
var statusFieldControl = formContext.getControl("new_status");

// Get the attribute options
var options = statusFieldControl.getAttribute().getOptions();

// Clear existing options
statusFieldControl.clearOptions();

// Add only allowed options back
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i];
    
    if (allowedOptionValues.indexOf(option.value) !== -1) {
        statusFieldControl.addOption(option);
    }
}
```

and it works perfectly.